# Can someone please breakdown this function step by step and explain me what it is doing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

`adjacentElementsProduct` is a function that takes an array as an input and we need to find and return the adjacent elements whose product is greater among all the adjacent elements.

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(arr) {
  return Math.max(...arr.slice(1).map((x, i) => [x * arr[i]]))
}
```

Comment: What exactly is unclear about this code? See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements). Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) about objects and methods you don’t understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function executes as follows -

### Explanation -

- It creates a copy of original array firstly using `slice(1)` (read about [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)), which basically can be understood as the function creating a new array from the original one with the first element removed.
- Then, the function maps over the newly created array. Here, the map is taking two parameters in the callback function which are

  1. **`x`** - The **Value** of the element and
  2. **`i`** - The **Index** of the element.
- **IMPORTANT STUFF HAPPENS HERE**: Note that here, the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is returning an array with elements being the product of `x` (which is the current element under iteration of our newly created array) and `arr[i]` (which is the element at index `i` in our original array).

  So, essentially we are **multiplying adjacent elements** in each loop inside `map()`, since we have removed the first element while creating our copy array.
- Now, this `map()`, as we know will return an array of elements which are nothing but the **multiplications of `x` and `arr[i]` for each element `x` of newly created array**. As already stated, its just the array of multiplication of all the adjacent elements. This array is spread into separate parameters using the [spread operator syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) and then passed to [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) which will return the maximum of all elements in the adjacent multiplication result array.

---

### Demonstration -

**Eg.** Suppose our original array is -

```
[3,4,8,2,1]
```

1. Now, the first thing that will happen is a new copy of array will be created with the first element removed. So, `newArr = [4,8,2,1]`
2. Nextly, we are mapping over this array. `map()` callback is used with two parameters, first one being value and second one being the index currently it is on. So, we are just mapping throughout our `newArr` and then returning the product of `x` and `arr[i]`. So, it happens as -

   - `x = 4` and `i = 0` - Here, we will return `x*arr[i]` = `4*arr[0]` = `4*3` = `12`.
   - `x = 8` and `i = 1` - We again return `x*arr[i]` = `8*4` = `32`.
   - `x = 2` and `i = 2` - We again return `x*arr[i]` = `2*8` = `16`.
   - `x = 1` and `i = 3` - We again return `x*arr[i]` = `1*2` = `2`.
3. **Do note** that what the function did above is nothing but just calculated the products of all adjacent element in the original array.
4. Now, `map()` returns an array of all these values that we have calculated. The array is - `[12,32,16,2]`. This array is split into discrete parameters and passed to `Math.max()` function which will just return the max of all these.
5. We get our answer as `Math.max(...[12,32,16,2])` = `Math.max(12,32,16,2)` = `32`

---

```js
const myArr = [3,4,8,2,1];

function adjacentElementsProduct(arr) {
  return Math.max(...arr.slice(1).map((x, i) => [x * arr[i]]))
  // 1. Creates new array - [4,8,2,1] using arr.slice(1)
  // 2. uses map over array to iterate over all elements of newly created array
  // 3. map returns an array which is array containing product of adjacent element of original array
  // 4. The array will be expanded into arguments using spread operator
  // 5. Math.max will return the maximum of all these arguments (which are just the multiplication of all adjacent elements of our original array)
}

console.log(adjacentElementsProduct(myArr))
```

---

Hope this clears the things.

Comment: thanks for clearing.. nicely explained.. i was just not clear about why we are slicing the 0th index of the original array. also  i thought that the map function was taking i(index) from the newly created array.

Answer (score 0):

So:

1. `arr.slice(1)` returns all the elements in the array except the first
2. `.map((x,i)=>[x*arr[i]])` will create an array pushing in it all the things that the callback return, and the the callback are returning the product of the current element with `arr[i]` which since on the step 1 we have taken out the first, `arr[i]` will be the previous (so will be something like `[[first number * second], [second * third], [third * fourth], ...]`)
3. `...result` is the spread operator, and what it will do is pass the first element of the array `result` as first parameter to `Math.max`, the second element as second parameter...
4. `Math.max(...result)` will just return the max element of the elements passed as parameter

At the end:

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(arr) {
  let res = arr.slice(1); // every element except first
  res = res.map((x,i)=>x*arr[i]) // array like [[first number of  of arr * third number of arr], [third * fourth], ...]
  return Math.max(...res) // max value of res
}
```